# How to add magento 2 location based search product

Tags: magento2, php, database, third-party-module

[image]

Like this how to do in magento 2 location based product search

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think to this is a store location search type functionality.  You can get extensions for this.

https://amasty.com/store-locator-for-magento-2.html

Is a good example. But I'm aware this isn't quite what you want. I think what you want is bespoke and you will have to either develop something yourself or hire a developer who can.